# Sending the body of a page to another server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to send the body of a page (i.e. all of the HTML code/DOM) from a page on one server to another and then receive a response? The method used doesn't really matter, but I do have access to jQuery functions if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by sending...

```
$("html").html();
```

...in an ajax call:

```
var data = $("html").html();
$.ajax({
    url: "/echo/json/",
    data: data,
    type: "POST"
}).done(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brandonscript/p5zEW/

(See console for body output).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$.get( "somePage.html", 
       function( pageData ) {
         $.post("targetPage.php", pageData, function( data ) {
         alert("Done!");
       },
       "html"
     );
});
```